# Array push with Key and Value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm struggling a little bit with this JQUERY code. How do i get the value of an input number and stored it array? Below is my sample Code.

```js
var arr = [];
$('.tblPartial input[type="number"]').each(function(i) {
  arr.push(this.id);
});
$.each(arr, function(i, v) {
  var split = v.split('_');
  var expCount = $('#ec_' + split[1] + '.expCount').html();
  var inputCount = $('#' + v + '.inputCount').val();
  console.log(expCount + "\n" + inputCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Output:**

EXPCOUNT HTML Has a value of 1; which is good and nothing to care about.
inputCount value is 0, but the actual it has 1.

As i collaborate with the codes, i saw that i only got the index, and the id of my item. **That's my Bad Idea**. I need those id, and also i need the value of that element. Do i need to use Multidimensional array here? how to achieve this? thanks!

```js
$.post(self.baseUrl + "ShowingCountDetails", {CountNo: countno}, function (data) {
            var ctr = 0;
            var table = $('#partialTbl tbody');
            $('#ICnoPartial').val(data.CountDetails[0].CountNo);                
            table.empty();
            $.each(data.CountDetails, function (i, v) {
                ctr++;
                var ctrtd = $('<td/>').append(ctr);
                var itemCode = $('<td/>').append(v.ItemCode);
                var desc = $('<td/>').append(v.Description);
                var ActualStock = $('<td/>',{
                    'id': 'ec_' + v.ItemId,
                    'class': 'expCount',
                    'value': v.ActualStock
                    }).append(v.ActualStock);
                var inputNum = $('<input />', {
                    'type': 'number',
                    'value': v.CountTemp,
                    'class': "inputCount form-control input-sm",
                    'id': "inp_" + v.ItemId,
                    //'name': v.ItemId
                });
                var inputCount1 = $('<td/>').append(inputNum); 
                var uom = $('<td/>').append(v.Uom);
                //var matched = $('<td/>').append();
                var icon = $('<i />', {
                    'class': "iconChecked fa fa-check aria-hidden=true",
                    'id': "icon_" + v.ItemId,
                    'style': 'color : #00a65a; text-align:center;'
                });
                var icontd = $('<i />', { // X Icon
                    'class': "iconStop fa fa-times aria-hidden=true",
                    'id': "icon1_" + v.ItemId,
                    'style': 'color : #f90808;'
                });
                var deleteButton = $('<button />', {
                    'type': 'button',
                    'class': 'btn btn-danger btn-xs btnDelete',
                    'id': v.ItemId
                }).append('<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

                var del = $('<td/>').append(deleteButton);
                var iconTD = $('<td/>', { 'style': 'text-align:center;'}).append(icon).append(icontd);
                var row = $('<tr/>').append(ctrtd).append(itemCode).append(desc).append(ActualStock).append(inputCount1).append(uom).append(iconTD).append(del);
                table.append(row);
            });
        }).success(function () {
            self.ifMatch(true);
            self.loadIconValidation(true);
            self.deleteButtonClicked();
            });
```

The code first above, is a part of my validation.

Comment: You're missing the end of the `$.each()` function.

Comment: Can you post an example of your HTML?

Comment: I suspect you need a space before `.expCount`, but it's hard to tell without the HTML.

Comment: And the same thing before `.inputCount`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, i editted now my code.
CertainPerformance,=> Okay i'll try to post also on how i render my html. It is written also in Jquery.

Comment: You're still missing `)` at the end. Why is it so hard for you to copy the code from the real site?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Here is how i render my HTML code.
Barmar => Okay my bad, just struggling deleting comments on my code so you can find whats the real content. Sorry

Comment: Is there anthing that can do like this? array.push(Key,Value)? Thanks guys.

Comment: Yes array[key] = value.

Comment: I already found out a solution. And i want to post it but i got banned and i dont know why. 
i added this code
** var arrVal = []; // In this array declaration will store the value i needed
   arrVal.push($(this).val()); //Store the value inside the array.
 $.each(arr, function (i, v) {
                var value = arrVal[i]; // Get's the value with the same index in the first declared array
                }); **
Thank you guys